# specifing '-c path/pytest.ini' in pytest.main() only uses function pattern(python_functions) for one file

Tags: python, pytest

I what to call pytest.main this way:

```
pytest.main(['-c'.'path\pytest.ini', 'tests\testfile1::src_func1','tests\testfile2::src_func2'])
```

so basically I want to have the pytest.ini test outside the tests folder and call a list of tests from different files on the tests folder.  I have defined a pattern for the test names in the pytest.ini: src_* in this example.
My problem is that the src_* pattern is only detected for first file that is the argument right next to the

```
'-c'.'path/pytest.ini', 'tests\testfile1::src_func1'
```

and not for the

```
'tests\testfile2::src_func2'
```

so the test in testfile2 is not found. The funny thing is that when the pytest.ini is inside the tests folder then I call pytest like

```
pytest.main(['tests\testfile1::src_func1','tests\testfile2::src_func2'])
```

and both tests on both files are detected, so the pattern src_* from the pytest.ini works as expected.
The question is why is the src_* not used for the  second file when the pytest.ini is outside the tests folder?

I have debugged pytest and search online and until now I know the -c flag should be used to use a pytest.ini outside the test folder but for my application it doesnt work as it should, or Im using it the wrong way.

Comment: So I have been debugging for days, and made one small finding until now: on _pytest\main.py on line 772,  When the pytest.ini is not inside the test folder  and the -c flag is used, for each .py that I pass on my command to pytest.main() a module is created, but is not given a name so only the first file tests get collected and the tests from the second file since the second node/file also has no name it is considered as already loaded so is not collected. Will continue post if I make some progress.

Comment: have started a discussion in github: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/10856

Comment: correction to my first comment: it should be module and not node. The variable on the code where I discoverd this is named node but its actually a pytest module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to add --rootdir=pathtofolder\tests as command line argument on the commands passed to pytest.main(), more explanation here : https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/10856#discussioncomment-5513661